# Calculate Euclidean distance between RGB vectors in a large matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, rgb, euclidean-distance

I have this RGB matrix of a set of different pixels. (N pixels => n rows, RGB => 3 columns). I have to calculate the minimum RGB distance between any two pixels from this matrix. I tried the loop approach, but because the set is too big (let's say N=24000), it looks like it will take forever for the program to finish. Is there another approach? I read about `pdist`, but the RGB Euclidean distance cannot be used with it.

```
k=1;
for i = 1:N
    for j = 1:N
        if (i~=j)
            dist_vect(k)=RGB_dist(U(i,1),U(j,1),U(i,2),U(j,2),U(i,3),U(j,3))
        k=k+1;
        end
    end
end
```

Euclidean distance between two pixels:
[image]
So, pdist syntax would be like this: `D=pdist2(U,U,@calc_distance());`, where U is obtained like this:

```
rgbImage = imread('peppers.png');
rgb_columns = reshape(rgbImage, [], 3)    
[U, m, n] = unique(rgb_columns, 'rows','stable');
```

But if `pdist2` does the loops itself, how should I enter the parameters for my function?

```
function[distance]=RGB_dist(R1, R2, G1, G2, B1, B2),
```

where R1,G1,B1,R2,G2,B2 are the components of each pixel.

I made a new function like this:

```
function[distance]=RGB_dist(x,y)

  distance=sqrt(sum(((x-y)*[3;4;2]).^2,2));

end
```

and I called it `D=pdist(U,U,@RGB_dist);` and I got 'Error using pdist (line 132)
The 'DISTANCE' argument must be a
string or a function.'

Testing RGB_dist new function alone, with these input set

```
x=[62,29,64;
    63,31,62;
    65,29,60;
    63,29,62;
    63,31,62;];


d=RGB_dist(x,x);
disp(d);
```

outputs only values of 0.

Comment: What is `RBG_dist`? I can't find it with Google

Comment: `RGB_dist` is simply the distance between two colour pixels using the red, green and blue channels.  Though we don't have the source code, it should be fairly easy to implement, depending on what criteria you use.  OP: What **kind of** distance measure do you want to implement?

Comment: You **can** use `pdist`.  You simply have to specify **your own** distance function to it.  I'll write an answer for you but I need to know what distance measure you want first.  Is it the Euclidean distance as what your post title says?

Comment: Put your components together, they are, after all, a vector, and you're looking for a distance between 2 vectors. Something like `RGB_dist = @(x,y)sqrt(sum(((x-y)*[3;4;2]).^2,2))` should work.

Comment: @jpjacobs I defined the function as you suggested and I tried to call it pdist(U,U,RGB_dist), but I get this error: 'MTIMES is not fully supported for integer classes. At least one input must be
scalar.
To compute elementwise TIMES, use TIMES (.*) instead.' As the error suggested, I tried '.*' instead of '*' and I get another one: 'Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.'

Comment: Cast your `U` matrix to double then try again.  FWIW, you should really provide **all** information so it prevents us from modifying our posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to what your post says, you **can** use the Euclidean distance as part of `pdist`.  You have to **specify** it as a flag when you call `pdist`.

The loop you have described above can simply be computed by:

```
dist_vect = pdist(U, 'euclidean');
```

This should compute the `L2` norm between each unique pair of rows.  Seeing that your matrix has a RGB pixel per row, and each column represents a single channel, `pdist` should totally be fine for your application.

If you want to display this as a **distance matrix**, where row `i` and column `j` corresponds to the distance between a pixel in row `i` and row `j` of your matrix `U`, you can use `squareform`.

```
dist_matrix = squareform(dist_vect);
```

As an additional bonus, if you want to find which two pixels in your matrix share the smallest distance, you can simply do a `find` search on the lower triangular half of `dist_matrix`.  The diagonals of `dist_matrix` are going to be all **zero** as any vector whose distance to itself should be 0.  In addition, this matrix is symmetric and so the upper triangular half should be equal to the lower triangular half.  Therefore, we can set the diagonal and the upper triangular half to `Inf`, then search for the minimum for those elements that are remaining.  In other words:

```
indices_to_set = true(size(dist_matrix));
indices_to_set = triu(indices_to_set);
dist_matrix(indices_to_set) = Inf;
[v1,v2] = find(dist_matrix == min(dist_matrix(:)), 1);
```

`v1` and `v2` will thus contain the rows of `U` where those RGB pixels contained the smallest Euclidean distance.  Note that we specify the second parameter as `1` as we want to find just one match, as what your post has stated as a requirement.  If you wish to find **all** vectors who match the same distance, simply remove the second parameter `1`.

---

## Edit - June 25th, 2014

Seeing as how you want to **weight** each component of the Euclidean distance, you can define your own custom function to calculate distances between two RGB pixels.  As such, instead of specifying `euclidean`, you can specify **your own** function which can calculate the distances between two vectors within your matrix by calling `pdist` like so:

```
pdist(x, @(XI,XJ) ...);
```

`@(XI,XJ)...` is an anonymous function that takes in a vector `XI` and a matrix `XJ`.  For `pdist` you need to make sure that the custom distance function takes in `XI` as a `1 x N` vector which is a single **row** of pixels.  `XJ` is then a `M x N` matrix that contains multiple rows of pixels.  As such, this function needs to return a `M x 1` vector of distances.  Therefore, we can achieve your weighted Euclidean distance as so:

```
weights = [3;4;2];
weuc = @(XI, XJ, W) sqrt(bsxfun(@minus, XI, XJ).^2 * W);
dist_matrix = pdist(double(U), @(XI, XJ) weuc(XI, XJ, weights));
```

`bsxfun` can handle that nicely as it will replicate `XI` for as many rows as we need to, and it should compute this single vector with every single element in `XJ` by subtracting.  We thus square each of the differences, weight by `weights`, then take the square root and sum.  Note that I didn't use `sum(X,2)`, but I used vector algebra to compute the sum.  If you recall, we are simply computing the **dot product** between the square distance of each component with a weight.  In other words, `x^{T}y` where `x` is the square distance of each component and `y` are the weights for each component.  You could do `sum(X,2)` if you like, but I find this to be more elegant and easy to read... plus it's less code!

Now that I know how you're obtaining `U`, the type is `uint8` so you need to cast the image to `double` before we do anything.  This should achieve your weighted Euclidean distance as we talked about.

As a check, let's put in your matrix in your example, then run it through `pdist` then `squareform`

```
x=[62,29,64;
63,31,62;
65,29,60;
63,29,62;
63,31,62];
weights = [3;4;2];
weuc = @(XI, XJ, W) sqrt(bsxfun(@minus,XI,XJ).^2 * W);
%// Make sure you CAST TO DOUBLE, as your image is uint8
%// We don't have to do it here as x is already a double, but 
%// I would like to remind you to do so!
dist_vector = pdist(double(x), @(XI, XJ) weuc(XI, XJ, weights));
dist_matrix = squareform(dist_vector)

dist_matrix =

     0    5.1962    7.6811    3.3166    5.1962
5.1962         0    6.0000    4.0000         0
7.6811    6.0000         0    4.4721    6.0000
3.3166    4.0000    4.4721         0    4.0000
5.1962         0    6.0000    4.0000         0
```

As you can see, the distance between pixels 1 and 2 is `5.1962`.  To check, `sqrt(3*(63-62)^2 + 4*(31-29)^2 + 2*(64-62)^2) = sqrt(3 + 16 + 8) = sqrt(27) = 5.1962`.  You can do similar checks among elements within this matrix.  We can tell that the distance between pixels 5 and 2 is **0** as you have made these rows of pixels the same.  Also, the distance between each of themselves is also 0 (along the diagonal).  Cool!